# np.linalg.qr(A) or scipy.linalg.orth(A) for finding the orthogonal basis (python)

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, vector

If I have a vector space spanned by five vectors v1....v5, to find the orthogonal basis for A where A=[v1,v2...v5] and A is 5Xn

should I use `np.linalg.qr(A)` **or** `scipy.linalg.orth(A)`??

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that `sp.linalg.orth` uses the SVD while `np.linalg.qr` uses a QR factorization. Both factorizations are obtained via wrappers for LAPACK functions.

I don't think there is a strong preference for one over the other. The SVD will be slightly more stable but also a bit slower to compute. In practice I don't think you will really see much of a difference.

Comment: is QR decomposition provides an orthogonal basis for the column space of A? is that the same?

Comment: The column space is exactly the span of the columns of $A$ (also called the range). However it is not the same basis as the SVD.

Comment: if it is not the same, which one should I use

Comment: It depends on your application. Both give a set of vectors with the same span.

Comment: I need to project some entities vectors to a low dimensional subspace spanned by the vectors in A, but because the vectors in A are not orthogonal to each other I need to find the orthogonal basis

Comment: I think either will work fine, but you can always test it in your setup to compare the time and accuracy of both methods

Comment: The main difference is that the SVD vectors are, in a sense, in order of importance. If you approximate a random vector from the column-span of A as a linear combination of q < 5 vectors, the first q vectors from orth will generally give a much better approximation.

Answer (score 1):

The disadvantage of numpy's QR to find orthogonal basis is that it can not handle deficient rank matrix inherently. For example:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy

A = np.array([[3,5,6,6], [7,2,4,4], [9,1,8,8], [7,1,6,6]])
b = np.array([1,2,3,4]).reshape(-1, 1)

#use lstsq for verification
beta, *_ = np.linalg.lstsq(A, b, rcond=None)
bproj = A @ beta
array([[1.01782846],
       [2.14262769],
       [3.7844523 ],
       [2.84115002]])

#Try numpy's qr
Q, R = np.linalg.qr(A)
bproj = Q @ Q.T @ b
array([[1.],
       [2.],
       [3.],
       [4.]])
#Q here is a 4x4 orthonormal matrix. However, Col(A) is 3 dimensional.

#With scipy's ortho
Q = scipy.linalg.orth(A)
bproj = Q @ Q.T @ b
array([[1.01782846],
       [2.14262769],
       [3.7844523 ],
       [2.84115002]])
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to use:

```
scipy.linalg.orth(A)
```

The generally accepted rule is to use scipy.linalg - because it covers more functionality than np.linalg. Hope that helps!

Comment: Do I need to transpose the matrix A?

Comment: No, you do don't.  What is your application?

Comment: I need to project some entities vectors to a low dimensional subspace spanned by the vectors in A, but because the vectors in A are not orthogonal to each other I need to find the orthogonal basis

Comment: @Abrar, in that case, I would imagine sp.linalg.orth would be easier to use unless you need efficient access to the determinant.